# how to slice numpy array with an n*2 numpy index pythonicly?

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know how to describe my question, if there already exists answer please redirect this question. My question is, like code below:

```py
import numpy as np

idx = np.array([[1,3],[5,7], [9,11]], dtype=np.int64)
data = np.arange(30).reshape(2, 15)
need_list = []
for i in range(idx.shape[0]):
    need_list.append(data[:, idx[i, 0]:idx[i, 1]])
result = np.hstack(need_list)

'''The result would be
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10],
       [16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25]])
'''
```

The code above works well for me, but I think it's a little verbose, and I wonder if there is any pythonic way to slice `data` by `idx` without using `need_list` and for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With array slicing and [`np.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
arr = np.column_stack([data[:, slice(a[0], a[1])] for a in idx])
```

---

```
[[ 1  2  5  6  9 10]
 [16 17 20 21 24 25]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup:

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.array([[1,3],[5,7], [9,11]], dtype=np.int64)
data = np.arange(30).reshape(2, 15)
```

You could also convert your `idx` array to an array of column indices:

```
from itertools import starmap
cols = np.r_[ tuple(starmap(slice, idx)) ]
# or np.r_[ tuple(map(lambda x: slice(*x), idx)) ] if you don't want itertools
```

we have `cols`:

```
array([ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10], dtype=int64)
```

Now simply index:

```
out = data[:, cols]
```

`out`:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10],
       [16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25]])
```

Answer (score 0):

What the alternatives come down to,

Either you select the desired columns from `data` and then join them (with `hstack` or `column_stack` (or `concatenate` on axis 1):

```
In [21]: [data[:,i:j] for i,j in idx]
Out[21]: 
[array([[ 1,  2],
        [16, 17]]),
 array([[ 5,  6],
        [20, 21]]),
 array([[ 9, 10],
        [24, 25]])]
```

Or you construct advanced indexing arrays for the columns, join them, and then do the indexing:

```
In [22]: [np.arange(i,j) for i,j in idx]
Out[22]: 
[array([1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([5, 6], dtype=int64),
 array([ 9, 10], dtype=int64)]
```

Since the slice size is 2 for all indices, you could also construct the column indices with:

```
In [31]: idx[:,0,None]+np.arange(2)
Out[31]: 
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]], dtype=int64)
```

Flatten that and index:

```
In [34]: data[:,np.ravel(idx[:,0,None]+np.arange(2))]
Out[34]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6,  9, 10],
       [16, 17, 20, 21, 24, 25]])
```

`np.linspace` can also construct such a 2d array of indices.